# How do you validate radio buttons in a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php

I have a quiz that consists of multidimensional arrays. I want to be able to validate the radio buttons so that the echoed message appears and the user has to click on one of the radio buttons for each questions. My validation currently isn't working but I don't understand how to validate the radio buttons when they're being echoed in an input.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
$quiz = array(

'questions' => array(
   "1. How many different stages of belts are there? <br>",  
   "2. What are the four basic kicks of Tae Kwon Do? <br>", 
   "3. When was Tae Kwon Do taught in America? <br>", 
   "4. What does Tae Kwon Do mean? <br>", 
   "5. Where did Tae Kwon Do originate? <br>",
   ), 

'choices' => array(
            array("A. 10", "B. 8", "C. 11 <br>"),
            array("A. Ax Kick, Flying Sidekick, Back kick, Front Kick", "B. Front Kick, Side Kick, Back Kick, Roundhouse Kick", "C. Front Kick, Back Kick, Side Kick, Hook Kick <br>"),
            array("A. 1963", "B. 1940s", "C. 1980 <br>"),
            array("A. The way of the foot and fist", "B. To fight with foot and fist", "C. To fight and defend <br>"),
            array("A. South Korea", "B. China", "C. Japan <br>"),
            ),

 'correct' => array("C. 11", 
                "B. Front Kick, Side Kick, Back Kick, Roundhouse Kick", 
                "A. 1963", 
                "A. The way of the foot and fist", 
                "A. South Korea"),
);//end of $quiz array


//Questions
foreach($quiz['questions'] as $i => $question){
    echo $question;

    foreach($quiz['choices'][$i] as $j => $choice){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='$i'>{$choice}<br>";
    }
    //Validation
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST[$i] == $quiz['correct'][$i]){
            echo 'Please select an answer.';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want: `"<input type='radio' name='selected[]' value='$id'>$choice</input>"` and do `print_r($_POST['selected'])`

Comment: When I do that it gives me, Notice: Undefined variable: id. Also wouldn't putting the brackets in the name='' cause extra arrays with only one element to be created?